# ¿Es posible configurar un virtualhost en un contenedor de docker con Apache?

Tags: apache, docker, virtualhost

les describo mi duda a continuación:

Actualmente cuento con Docker instalado en mi equipo con Windows. Tengo un contenedor Ubuntu 18.04, el cual tiene instalado PHP 7.2, Apache2, y MariaDB. El mapeo de los puertos es el siguiente:

```
docker run -it --name mi_contenedor -p 8080:80 -p 8081:3306 ubuntu:1804
```

Anteriormente, antes de utilizar Docker, tenia configurado un Virtual Host en mi equipo para un proyecto web, algo como `http://mi_proyecto.dev` para acceder a él en lugar el típico `http://localhost/proyectos/mi_proyecto`.

Ahora que cambié mi forma de trabajo a Docker, tengo mi proyecto trabajando perfectamente por el puerto 8080, algo así `http://localhost:8080/proyectos/mi_proyecto`, pero no encuentro la forma de crear un Virtual Host para acceder con `http://mi_proyecto.dev` a mi proyecto en mi actual contenedor de Docker.

Comment: Lo pudiste solucionar? busco lo mismo y la respuesta de Andres Sanchez no me sirvió. Por favor publica la respuesta si lo solucionaste. Saludos!

Comment: @ZiggyPop No, aún no lo he podido solucionar, e intentado varias formas y ninguna me ha funcionado. En un post que publiqué en el foro de docker, me dejaron este link [Docker Networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/), que leyera acerca del tema y lo intentara. A mi no me funcionó

Comment: Alguien pudo realizar este proceso ando buscando lo mismo actualmente, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que antes de ejecutar el contenedor con el **docker run** creas una imagen desde un Dockerfile, y en esa imagen tendrás instalado el apache.

Simplemente create un fichero virtualhost.
Ejemplo:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  <Directory /var/local/www/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>


    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/local/www/public/

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

si a este fichero lo llamas **000-default.conf** y lo guardas junto con el Dockerfile, simplemente crea una linea en tu Dockerfile:

```
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```